# Javascript updating variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used some javascript with some php. The jquery changes a php variable like it should... i echoed the new php variable and it shows, however my javascript variables don't change

```
<?php 
     $image ='<div id="myid"></div>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="storescripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var my_pic = new Image();
  my_pic.src = '<?php echo $image; ?>';
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function swapContent(cv){
    $("#myDiv").html("animated gif").show();
    var url ="myphpscript2.php";
    var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;

    $.post(url,{contentVar: cv, id: id,},function(data){
      $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
  }
</script>
```

These are the scripts used. I have no idea why just before the php variable will change but the other will just stay as ''

Comment: Don't confuse `java` and `javascript`.

Comment: *Only* the HTML in #myDiv will be updated by the postback. Inspect the returned (XHR) HTML to see what values are sent, and if they are as expected. If not, then they are probably not accessed correctly in PHP.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Just saying you don't know what's happening just tells us you don't understand your own code, so what do you expect it to do, where, and why? By explaining this to us, you can pinpoint where you think things are going wrong (and 9 out of 10 times, realise what's wrong all on your own, simply by explaining your code and realising that what you're explaining is not what the code says should happen)

Comment: Basicly im expecting the $image ='<div id="myid"></div>'; variable to update in the my_pic.src = '<?php echo $image; ?>'; and it isnt